# Reasons for receiving "RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: android

I am implementing **RadioGroup** in my application. For that I have imported `import android.widget.RadioGroup` and `implemented OnCheckedChangeListener`. But still I am getting this error:

> The method
>   setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the
>   type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (OpenedClass)

Java:

> OpenedClass.java

```
public class OpenedClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnCheckedChangeListener{

    TextView tv1,tv2;
    RadioGroup selectionList;
    Button rtn;
    String gotBread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);
        initlize();
        Bundle gotBusket = getIntent().getExtras();
        gotBread = gotBusket.getString("KEY");
        tv1.setText(gotBread);

    }
    private void initlize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        rtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
        rtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        selectionList = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgAnswers);
        selectionList.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.rCrazy:
            break;
        case R.id.rSuper:
            break;
        case R.id.rBoth:
            break;
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are importing an incorrect class of `OnCheckedChangeListener` for `RadioGroup`.

Replace:

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

with this one:

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

and fix your interface implementation as below:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
   switch(checkedId)
   {
      //your cases
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use Ctrl+Shift+O to fix your imports from time to time if using Eclipse IDE

Comment: may i know what is the difference between those two?

Comment: or mouse over your class and eclipse would automatically suggest you to pick the correct import  :)

Comment: @Neo Ctrl+Shift+O only added that

Comment: `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` is used by `CheckBox`. However, `RadioGroup` requires `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Answer (score 1):

During creating the oncheckedchangelistener(), specifying "`new  RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()`" instead of just  "`OnCheckedChangeListener()`" fixed the problem.

Adding the sample code for others reference.

```
RadioGroup rdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
    rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing an incorrect class of
OnCheckedChangeListener