# OnCheckedChangeListener conflict with checkBox vs radioGroup

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-radiogroup

I am working through a online tutorial building a tip calculator.  In the video the guy shows how to build an inline click listener.  I am trying to build click listeners for a checkbox and radio group.  However, there seems to be a conflict that I'm having trouble resolving.

Here is the setup for the checkbox change listener..

```
friendlyCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            checklistValues[0] = (friendlyCheckBox.isChecked())?4:0;

            setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
            updateTipFinalBill();

        }

    });
```

and here is the setup for the radioGroup change listener..

```
howHotRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


        }


    });
```

I'm getting this error with the radioGroup change listener

```
The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){})
```

After doing some research I came to this thread..  [Reasons for receiving "RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761597/reasons-for-receiving-radiogroup-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments)

Which tells me to import this

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

When I do import that I get this error

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener collides with another import statement
```

I believe that these are the two conflicting imports but when I replace one with the other my error just moves from my checkbox to my radioGroup.

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't import any of them, just the corresponding outer classes and then use the inner class name when creating the anonymous listener, i.e.

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
```

and then

```
howHotRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() ...
friendlyCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() ...
```